# Azure SAS Token for a specific file

Tags: azure-blob-storage, azure-data-lake

I'm building a file storage POC using Azure Data Lake (using hierarchical namespace). I need to generate SAS Token for a specific file stored in a directory structure. I couldn't find any example for doing this. Appreciate if there are any pointers or code snippet to do this.

Comment: What's the SDK you're using?

Comment: Azure.Storage.Files.DataLake version 12.8.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement in your earlier code as below:

I am simply writing the generated Blob SAS  URL to a file `WriteLines.txt`

```
using Azure;
using Azure.Storage;
using Azure.Storage.Files.DataLake;
using Azure.Storage.Files.DataLake.Models;
using Azure.Storage.Sas;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using NUnit.Framework;
using System.IO;

namespace DataLakeHelloWorld
{
    class Program
    {
       

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Starting....");
            try
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Executing...");
                CreateFileClientAsync_DirectoryAsync().Wait();
                Console.WriteLine("Done");
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e);
            }
        }


        static async Task CreateFileClientAsync_DirectoryAsync()
        {
            // Make StorageSharedKeyCredential to pass to the serviceClient
            string storageAccountName = "kteststorageeadls";
            string storageAccountKey = "6fAe+K8ARe8LH9Ah2HuLuEONpxxxxxxxxxSjLy3oVPAgj04m+zWZuy5X8p4/BaQTY8efzCj/X+On/FwmvgSo6g==";
            string dfsUri = "https://" + "kteststorageeadls" + ".dfs.core.windows.net";

            StorageSharedKeyCredential sharedKeyCredential = new StorageSharedKeyCredential(storageAccountName, storageAccountKey);

            // Create DataLakeServiceClient using StorageSharedKeyCredentials
            DataLakeServiceClient serviceClient = new DataLakeServiceClient(new Uri(dfsUri), sharedKeyCredential);

            // Create a DataLake Filesystem
            DataLakeFileSystemClient filesystem = serviceClient.GetFileSystemClient("my-filesystem-dfs");
            if (!await filesystem.ExistsAsync())
                await filesystem.CreateAsync();

            //Create a DataLake Directory
            DataLakeDirectoryClient directory = filesystem.CreateDirectory("my-dir");
            if (!await directory.ExistsAsync())
                await directory.CreateAsync();

            // Create a DataLake File using a DataLake Directory
            DataLakeFileClient file = directory.GetFileClient("my-file");
            if (!await file.ExistsAsync())
                await file.CreateAsync();

            // Verify we created one file
            var response = filesystem.GetPathsAsync();
            IAsyncEnumerator<PathItem> enumerator = response.GetAsyncEnumerator();
            Console.WriteLine(enumerator?.Current?.Name);

            //**********Start-add-from-here************

            DataLakeSasBuilder dataLakeSasBuilder = new DataLakeSasBuilder
            {
                StartsOn = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddHours(-1),
                ExpiresOn = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddHours(1),
                FileSystemName = file.FileSystemName.ToString()
            };

            dataLakeSasBuilder.SetPermissions(DataLakeFileSystemSasPermissions.Read);

            DataLakeUriBuilder dataLakeUriBuilder = new DataLakeUriBuilder(file.Uri)
            {
                Sas = dataLakeSasBuilder.ToSasQueryParameters(sharedKeyCredential)
            };

            DataLakeFileSystemClient sasFileSystemClient = new DataLakeFileSystemClient(dataLakeUriBuilder.ToUri());

            // To debug writing the SAS URL to a file in project dir
            Console.WriteLine(sasFileSystemClient);
            string name = sasFileSystemClient.Uri.ToString();
            File.WriteAllTextAsync("WriteLines.txt", name);

            //**********end************

            // Cleanup
            //await filesystem.DeleteAsync();

        }

    }
}
```

[image]

Here is how the actual Blob SAS URL for a single file `my-file` looks:

```
https://kteststorageeadls.dfs.core.windows.net/my-filesystem-dfs/my-dir/my-file?sv=2020-08-04&st=2021-10-13T15%3A39%3A26Z&se=2021-10-13T17%3A36%3A26Z&sr=c&sp=r&sig=APeC5UTh7fEkzL5czAM%2B124XXE9zw%2FpTJLuvlqVQEko%3D
```

Comment: Awesome!! This works great. I verified by trying access different file and got failure

Comment: Glad I could be of help 

Answer (score 0):

For generating a SAS URL for a file, the method you would want to call is [`DataLakeFileSystemClient.GenerateSasUri`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.storage.files.datalake.datalakefilesystemclient.generatesasuri?view=azure-dotnet).

Here's a sample code to generate a SAS URI:

```
public async Task SetPermissions_Filesystem(DataLakeFileSystemSasPermissions permissions)
{
    // Arrange
    await using DisposingFileSystem test = await GetNewFileSystem();

    DataLakeSasBuilder dataLakeSasBuilder = new DataLakeSasBuilder
    {
        StartsOn = Recording.UtcNow.AddHours(-1),
        ExpiresOn = Recording.UtcNow.AddHours(1),
        FileSystemName = test.FileSystem.Name
    };

    dataLakeSasBuilder.SetPermissions(permissions);

    StorageSharedKeyCredential sharedKeyCredential = new StorageSharedKeyCredential(Tenants.TestConfigHierarchicalNamespace.AccountName, Tenants.TestConfigHierarchicalNamespace.AccountKey);

    DataLakeUriBuilder dataLakeUriBuilder = new DataLakeUriBuilder(test.FileSystem.Uri)
    {
        Sas = dataLakeSasBuilder.ToSasQueryParameters(sharedKeyCredential)
    };

    DataLakeFileSystemClient sasFileSystemClient = InstrumentClient(new DataLakeFileSystemClient(dataLakeUriBuilder.ToUri(), GetOptions()));

    // Act
    await foreach (PathItem pathItem in sasFileSystemClient.GetPathsAsync())
    {
        // Just make sure the call succeeds.
    }
}
```

I have taken this code from [`here`](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/main/sdk/storage/Azure.Storage.Files.DataLake/tests/DataLakeSasBuilderTests.cs).

Comment: Thanks for the snippet. I think above code grant permissions to the entire file system. I'm looking for SAS Token to specific directory or file.

Comment: Instead of `FileSystemName` in creating `DataLakeSasBuilder`, please use `Path` property. Please see [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.storage.sas.datalakesasbuilder?view=azure-dotnet#properties) for more details.

Comment: I tried below and got error (myblobfoo.dfs.core.windows.net:443)) (No such host is known. ). The host does exists and there are no restrictions to access.

            DataLakeDirectoryClient directory =
                await filesystem.CreateDirectoryAsync("my-dir");

            DataLakeSasBuilder dataLakeSasBuilder = new DataLakeSasBuilder
            {
                StartsOn = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddHours(-1),
                ExpiresOn = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddHours(1),
                Path = directory.Path,
                IsDirectory = true,
            };

Comment: for some reason as per your previous question, you tried to use `blob` in place of `dfs` in host name i.e. `myblobfoo.blob.core.windows.net` and you mentioned it worked. Maybe this is related https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/issues/20690